# How to set absolute position in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, position, absolute

I'm trying to set the `left` position of an absolute element with jQuery.

This is what I've tried:

```
var leftPercentage = 10 + '%';
var singleGrate = grateOne.append('<div class="single-grate"><div>');
singleGrate.css(left, leftPercentage);
```

I have also tried removing the percentage and using `px` but it didn't work.

I've also tried using `offset`, but while that works, it sets the element depending on the page, not the element containing the `div` I want to position.

I'm just lost as to how to get this to work. I followed a bunch of questions from stackoverflow but I'm pretty sure they are all very outdated because none of them worked.

What am I supposed to do here?

EDIT: Here's the codepen I am currently working on https://codepen.io/creativiii/pen/gyKjrm

Answer (score 1):

In the last line. You need to put `""` to `left` so the code will be:

```
singleGrate.css("left", leftPercentage);
```

Comment: Yeah no I also tried that, it doesn't work. I'm going to add a codepen to the first post so you can test it out if you want.

Comment: hmm... in your code `var singleGrate = grateOne.append('<div class="single-grate"><div>');` doesn't look right. `append`  won't return any element

Comment: I'm trying to console.log singleGrate and it seems to return an element

Comment: then please provide your `html` an fulll `js` codes

Comment: All of it is in the codepen I linked in the first post, here https://codepen.io/creativiii/pen/gyKjrm

Answer (score 0):

So apparently the problem was with `append()`, as it doesn't actually point to the appended element.

I changed my code to append the element to:

```
var singleGrate = $('<div class="single-grate"><div>').appendTo(grateOne);
```

Now `singleGrate` actually returns an element that I can then change with `css()`.